# States in a javaEE web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, state

I want to have a button in my java EE application that creates a report, a static document that gathers the database records that i used in my Java EE application (like the reports in the .NET that are made with the crystal report).

Anybody can help?? Is there any handy report tool for java EE?? or is there a way to integrate crystal report to Eclipse??

P.S: I'm using Hibernate framework

Comment: What do you mean by 'states' ? That is ambiguous and does not seem to be related to the rest of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really broad - but I recommend you to look at [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) (JSR-160).

JMX will tell you everything you would ever want to know about your application's state - including custom/application specific items. Eg. the Spring framework has good support for JMX.

Best way to get started with JMX is to read a book, such as ["JMX in Action"](http://www.manning.com/sullins/).

Comment: Thank you! I'm using hibernate framework! But can't I just use something like JReport?